# Rails showing multiple variations of cached page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx

I have a Rails app that is randomly showing either the old version or the new version of the view when the page is refreshed. I am wrapping the fragment's contents in a `cache(model_instance)` call, but nothing else. The app is behind nginx so my assumption is that nginx may be caching the content. I'm curious what is causing this issue and how to fix it.

Comment: How many servers do you have? Do you use Unicorn? If so how many master processes do you have running?

Comment: I have a single server. I am using Unicorn and have 2 worker processes (if that's what you mean by master processes).

Comment: Ok, a single server makes debugging straight forward. Within *cache {}* block put something like Rails.logger.debug "#{Time.now.to_i}" and share the logs

Comment: Thats the thing, I even took out the cache block and it is still doing it. I also checked nginx and don't see that caching is enabled.

Comment: ok, let's check if you have only 1 Unicorn master, please do: ps aux|grep unicorn

Comment: showing 2 masters and 4 workers, should I kill the processes and restart unicorn fresh?

Comment: So I killed some old processes that shouldn't have been around and it fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help debugging.

Comment: Keep only one master with their workers, make sure you send HUP signal to reload an app OR combination of USR2+QUIT in case of *preload_app true*.